# Why does this makefile loop infinitely, but only on one machine?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider the following makefile:

```
-include target.d

build:

%.d: %.c
    @echo ">>> %.d: %.c"
    touch $@

target.d: dependency
#   @echo ">>> target.d: dependency"

dependency:
    @echo ">>> dependency"

.PHONY: build
```

If you place this in a directory with two (empty) files, target.d and target.c and run `make`, then on one VM I use it produces the following output:

```sh
$ make
>>> dependency
>>> %.d: %.c
touch target.d
>>> dependency
>>> %.d: %.c
touch target.d
make: Nothing to be done for `build'.
```

On another VM, it loops infinitely. Both VMs are running Centos7, and both of them are using the same version of GNU make (3.82).

(Note: if you uncomment the commented out line below the `target.d` target, then both produce the exact same output; that behavior makes sense to me, at least)

I am aware that by adding the recipe to the `target.d: dependency` makes it prioritise that recipe over the generic one, while simply adding a dependency. But what I don't understand is why one system causes an infinite loop to occur while another extremely similar system does not.

What is the reason for this strange behaviour?

(EDIT: I found out I can simplify the makefile and still see the same behaviour)

Comment: Does `target.d` already exist on both systems when you run `make`?  What happens if you specify the target explicitly using `make build`?

Comment: Can you provide a directory listing from the machine where it loops?

Comment: The directory listing on both machines is identical, and in both cases target.d exists.

Comment: (If target.d does not exist then Make does not run indefinitely... although if I change the `rm target.d` to an `rm -f target.d` then I still get the infinite loop)

Comment: It might have to do with your `touch` on the other build machine.   First, try adding `$(info $SHELL)` from the top of your makefile.   Then try running `which touch` and  `touch foo` on both build machines under whatever shell the make is using.   If one of them hangs, this will be your issue.

Comment: Sorry, when you say loops infinately, do you mean it simply hangs (unresponsive), or that it is trying to build target.d over and over?  (My last comment was on the assumption it simply becomes unresponsive).     If it's trying to build over and over, check that target.d is not a soft link to target.c, and that target.c is not a directory...

Comment: @HardcoreHenry - Sorry if I wasn't clear; it tries to build target.d over and over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as @code_fodder's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66284534/3351992) suggested, the entire makefile can be simplified heavily to

```
-include a

a: b
    touch a

b:
    @echo b
```

There is a valid question as to whether or not the inclusion of a makefile that you create is a good idea; As stated in the comments above, this is a distillation of part of a build system that I am working with but do not have control over, so c'est la vie.

So there remains the question as to why this behaves differently on two different systems?

The problem turned out to be the following: one VM was run on a remote server, and the other VM was being run locally. In particular, my host machine is a mac and I was sharing some of the file system between the mac and the VM. It appears that the filesystem that I am using on my Mac only keeps timestamps to second precision, while that on the VMs is kept to sub-millisecond precision. As a consequence the Mac doesn't pick up the "updated" file.

I was able to see this on the VM that shares files with the mac by adding sleep commands of various lengths:

```
-include a

a: b
    sleep 0.8
    touch a

b:
    @echo b
```

which would cause it to run a finite, but quasi-random number of times. Or, more simply, running `make; make` which yields

```
$ make; make
b
touch a
b
touch a
make: `a' is up to date.
b
touch a
make: `a' is up to date.
```

i.e. running `make` twice in short succession lets the second run see the updated timestamp of the first, and so it doesn't trigger a second time.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is with having a target called `target.d` that is the same as the include file `target.d` such that when you edit target.d by touching it this somehow invokes an "undefined" behaviour. It seems like in this case it is triggering a re-call of the makefile. I can distil your problem down to this:

```
-include target.d

target.d: dep
    touch target.d

dep:
    @echo dep
```

With the only files that exist being: `makefile`. `target.d` is created on the first run of `make`.

```sh
$ ls
makefile
$ make
dep
touch target.d
dep
touch target.d
dep
touch target.d
     :
    etc
     :
$ ls
makefile target.d
```

I do not believe it is correct to have a target that is also an item you include in your makefile. Usually with `.d` (e.g. auto generated dep files with gcc) you would generate these files in a compile rule like `%.o: %.c ...` which creates the .o and .d files. Then you have your `include %.d` type line. But you should not have a target to generate .d files directly. I do not think this is valid - please someone correct me if I am wrong here.

E.g. makefile that I think you intend:

```
-include target.d

.PHONY: build
build: target.o

# Simulates a compile line that generates and object file (.o) and dependency file (.d)
target.o: target.c dependency
    touch target.o
    touch target.d

.PHONY: dependency
dependency:
    @echo ">>> dependency"
```

output:

```sh
$ ls
makefile target.c
$ make
>>> dependency
touch target.o
touch target.d
$ ls
makefile  target.c  target.d  target.o
```

Comment: Well... this is a simplification of an issue that I found in a build system that I have inherited; it does naturally use `include target.d` (or some equivalent) which is used to generated the .o and .d files at the same time.

Comment: What you describe, though, is part of the problem in a sense, but the other part of the question of course is why does it behave separately on the two systems? That turns out to be a fun story, which I'll probably write up in a couple of days to help anyone who stumbles upon the same problem...

Comment: @SimonRose yes that would be interesting to know what you find out. I tested in on windows WSL for convenience. But still the point is that the targets should be converted to be the .o files not the .d files - might be a pain, but that is certainly what I would do.